# Documents "checked out or locked" but checkout has never been enabled?

Tags: sharepoint-online, error

My business partner has a horrible time opening documents.  She is not very technical and so her problems often have surprising solutions.  but this one has me baffled.

We will work together on a SharePoint-Online document, opened from the browser using the "Open in Word" option which is default.  However once a day or so, she will create a V2 document claiming "*I couldn't edit the original because I got the error that the document was checked out or locked...*".

I have never enabled the checkout option in that library - or ANY library in this site collection.  I just checked again this morning: "Version Settings - Require documents to be checked out = NO".

HOW is the managing to get this error?  It is only her having the issue.

Comment: This is not suggested but at **last option** You can download copy of document ,delete from live and upload same document

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't set your library to **require** check-ou, you may still have checked-out documents in the following situtations:

1. You manually check-out the document from the Library (select the document, choose "check-out").
2. You open the document in Word and let it open (this leads to a not-visible check-out state, known as "short-term" check-out, as long as the document is opened somewhere, or if Word was unproperly closed).
3. You upload a document in a library where you have required properties, and you don't fill-up these properties (this can also easily happen if you copy/paste or drag/drop a batch of files).
4. You check-out the document from Word ("File" menu, "Info" section, "Manage document" button).

Answer (score 1):

-- *I know this comment is 6,5 years later, but I'm just making it in case others stumble upon this thread.* --

I had the same situation and in my case this was caused by a Column setting combination of

1. Default Value (value)
2. Enforce unique values (slider)

Each document was automatically in conflict and Sharepoint checks out the document automatically as some sort of failsafe/workaround.

Hopefully this helps some.